# Defining 2 types of subsubsections KOMAscript

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I'd like to have 2 styles of subsubsections with KOMA: one that starts on a new line, and one that starts on the same line (`\subsubsectionS`). I thought this would work, but it does not:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
beforeskip=0.75\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,%
afterskip=-3ex,%
runin=true, % text on same line
]{subsubsection}

\let\subsubsectionS\subsubsection  % subsubsection on Same line

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
beforeskip=0.75\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,%
afterskip=0.01mm,%
runin=false, % text on same line
]{subsubsection}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question and I do not know, if both `subsubsection` and `subsubsectionS` should have the same level und should use the same counter.

`\RedeclareSectionCommand` redefines other macros depending on the name of the section level in its second argument.Therefore your solution can not work.

You have to use `\DeclareNewSectionCommand` to define `subsubsectionS`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
beforeskip=0.75\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,%
afterskip=0pt,%
runin=false,
]{subsubsection}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=subsubsection,
  indent:=subsubsection,
  numwidth:=subsubsection
]{tocline}{subsubsectionS}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
  style=section,
  level=\subsubsectionnumdepth,
  counterwithin=subsection,
  beforeskip=0.75\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,%
  afterskip=-3ex,%
  runin=true, % text on same line
  indent=0pt
]{subsubsectionS}

\makeatletter
  \let\c@subsubsectionS\c@subsubsection% use the same counter as subsubsection
  \let\cl@subsubsectionS\cl@subsubsection% use the same reset list as subsubsection
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\blindtext
\subsubsectionS{A subsubsectionS}\blindtext
\subsection{Next subsubsection}
\subsubsectionS{Another subsectionS}\blindtext
\subsubsection{Another subsection}\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remark:** The `:` syntax in the optional argument of `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` is only available from KOMA-Script version 3.27. But you can also define the settings `style`, `level`, `indent` and `numwidth` via `\DeclareNewSectionCommand`. Then they are all given the prefix `toc` and explicit values must be specified. This also works with older KOMA-Script versions.

```latex
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
  style=section,
  level=\subsubsectionnumdepth,
  counterwithin=subsection,
  beforeskip=0.75\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,%
  afterskip=-3ex,%
  runin=true, % text on same line
  indent=0pt,
  tocstyle=tocline,
  toclevel=\subsubsectiontocdepth,
  tocindent=3.8em,
  tocnumwidth=3.2em
]{subsubsectionS}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer. I only needed the different formatting for one chunk of the body, and I found that `{\RedeclareSectionCommand[kwvals]{subsubsection} ... newsubsectioncontent}` worked for my needs. I was confused as to why the `\let` didn't work.