# change font size of bibliography title

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning

I want to change the font size of the bibliography title. Namely I want `A. References` at the end of the document to be the same font size as the first section `Section with large font`. As I need different section font sizes it's no option to change the sizes globally.[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nottoc, numbib]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \section[Section with large font]{\huge Section with large font}
    \lipsum[10] \cite{test} 
    \section{Section with standard font}
    \lipsum[5]
    \bibliography{test}
    
\end{document}
```

The content of `test.bib` is:

```
@misc{test,
author = {testauthor},
title = {{Test Title}},
url = {https://www.domain.com},
year = {2020}
}
```

EDIT: I got a little further by adding `\addtokomafont{section}{\Huge}` before and `\addtokomafont{section}{\Large}` after the section whose font size I want to change. By trial and error I found out the default value of the section size is `\Large`. Is there a better way to reset the `\addtokomafont{section}{\Huge}` command to the default value?

```
\documentclass[bibliography = totocnumbered]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \addtokomafont{section}{\Huge}
    \section{Section with large font}
    \addtokomafont{section}{\Large}
    \lipsum[10] \cite{test} 
    \section{Section with standard font}
    \lipsum[5]
    \addtokomafont{section}{\Huge}
    \bibliography{test}
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \addtokomafont{section}{\Large}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As you are using the `KOMA-script` class (`scrartcl`, `scrbook`...) there is actually no need to load `tocbibind`. KOMA is extremely flexible and you might want to [look into](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#page=147) the options pertaining to "bibliography". You can set the font size, the TOC behavior, whether it is numbered...

Comment: Also, I'd recommend a more organic solution to increase the font size of your Section 1. You have forced the *text* to be `\huge`, but the attendant *section number* ("1.") is still small. Again, [KOMA-script](see https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#page=95) gives you a lot of freedom to customize your sectioning commands – either globally or, if you need it, by creating special sectioning commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate questions: (1) headings in general and (2) heading for the bibliography.

### (1) Section headings: (KOMA-script): font size

The cleanest way to go about this would be to define one or more custom section-level commands, each with the desired font size (following the approach outlined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/538041/)).

It is less hacky and error-prone than specifying the font size before each section via `\addtokomafont{section}{<size>}`.

This is how `\section` is introduced in `scrartcl.cls`:

```
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  level=1,%
  indent=\z@,%
  beforeskip=-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex,%
  afterskip=2.3ex \@plus.2ex,%
  tocstyle=section,%
  tocindent=0pt,%
  tocnumwidth=1.5em%
]{section}
```

We copy this and choose a larger font:

```
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  level=1,%
  font=\Huge,%
  indent=\z@,%
  beforeskip=-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex,%
  afterskip=2.3ex \@plus.2ex,%
  tocstyle=section,%
  tocindent=0pt,%
  toclevel=1,%
  tocnumwidth=1.5em%
]{specialsection}
```

`specialsection` should use a shared sequential numbering with vanilla `section`s, not two parallel numberings:

```
\let\c@specialsection\c@section
\let\cl@specialsection\cl@section
```

See the **MWE** below.

### (2) Bibliography heading (bibtex): font size

As you found out, `tocbibind` is not really needed to customize the bibliography's sectioning properties, given the wealth of options provided by `KOMA-script`.

As for the font size: I am not aware of a clean `bibtex` way to *redefine the format* of the bibliography heading accordingly to the custom sectioning format that we created (the way that `\renewcommand\refname{...}` can *redefine the title*).

We'll simply redefine `\section` to mean `\specialsection` *for the space of the bibliography*, so that this custom format doesn't spill over to later parts of the document. This is done by enclosing it in a group.

```
\begingroup
\let\section\specialsection
\bibliographystyle{...}
\bibliography{...}
\endgroup
```

This is just a marginal improvement on what you had already found. Note that with `biblatex`, there is a cleaner way to do this (and in 2022, do consider switching to `biblatex`, if you have the chance!):

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\defbibheading{SpecialBibHeadingStyle}{\specialsection{References}}
...
\begin{document}
...
\printbibliography[heading=SpecialBibHeadingStyle]
```

### MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.bib}
@misc{test,
author = {Author},
title = {Title}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[bibliography=numbered]{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  level=1,%
  font=\Huge,%
  indent=\z@,%
  beforeskip=-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex,%
  afterskip=2.3ex \@plus.2ex,%
  tocstyle=section,%
  tocindent=0pt,%
  toclevel=1,%
  tocnumwidth=1.5em%
]{specialsection}

\let\c@specialsection\c@section% use the same counter as section
\let\cl@specialsection\cl@section% use the same reset list as section
\makeatother

\usepackage{biblatex}       % biblatex
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\defbibheading{SpecialBibHeadingStyle}{\specialsection{References}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\specialsection{Huge section}

\section{Large section}
\cite{test}

%\begingroup                % bibtex
%\let\section\specialsection
%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
%\bibliography{test}
%\endgroup

\printbibliography[heading=SpecialBibHeadingStyle]      % biblatex

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC and sections with different font sizes]